# OPC UA Test Stack Example

Tags: java, opc, opc-ua

I am new to OPC UA and am puzzled with how the on... methods are triggered.
Quoting the example from TestStackServer:

TestStackExample.java:

```
/* ========================================================================
 * Copyright (c) 2005-2010 The OPC Foundation, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * OPC Foundation MIT License 1.00
 * 
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
 * obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
 * files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
 * restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
 * copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
 * Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
 * conditions:
 * 
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
 * included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
 * NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
 * HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
 * WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
 * OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 * The complete license agreement can be found here:
 * http://opcfoundation.org/License/MIT/1.00/
 * ======================================================================*/

package org.opcfoundation.ua.examples;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.application.Application;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.application.Client;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.application.Server;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.application.TestStackService;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.builtintypes.Variant;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.core.EndpointDescription;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.core.MessageSecurityMode;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.core.TestStackRequest;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.core.TestStackResponse;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.examples.certs.ExampleKeys;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.ServiceChannel;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.security.Cert;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.security.CertificateValidator;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.security.KeyPair;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.security.PrivKey;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.security.SecurityMode;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.security.SecurityPolicy;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.utils.EndpointUtil;

/**
 * This example creates both a server and a client. 
 * The server is bound to port 6001 and serves to TestStack requests (See {@link TestStackService}) with echo.
 * The client connects to the server and makes a simple "Hello World" request and receives 
 * corresponding "Hello World" resopnse.
 * 
 */
public class TestStackExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //////////////  SERVER  //////////////
        // Create UA Server Application
        Application myServerApplication = new Application();
        myServerApplication.getOpctcpSettings().setCertificateValidator( CertificateValidator.ALLOW_ALL );
        myServerApplication.getHttpsSettings().setCertificateValidator( CertificateValidator.ALLOW_ALL );
        myServerApplication.getHttpsSettings().setHostnameVerifier( SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER );
        // Create UA Service Server
        Server myServer = new Server( myServerApplication );


        // Add a service to the server - TestStack echo
        myServer.addServiceHandler( new TestStackService() );

        // Load Servers's Application Instance Certificate from file
        KeyPair myServerApplicationInstanceCertificate = ExampleKeys.getKeyPair("server", 2048);
        KeyPair myServerHttpsKey = ExampleKeys.getKeyPair("https_server", 2048);
        // Add application instance certificate     
        myServerApplication.addApplicationInstanceCertificate( myServerApplicationInstanceCertificate );        
        myServerApplication.getHttpsSettings().setKeyPair( myServerHttpsKey );

        // Bind the endpoint for each network interface
        String hostname = EndpointUtil.getHostname();
        for (String addr : EndpointUtil.getInetAddressNames()) {
            String bindAddress     = "opc.tcp://"+addr+":6002/UAExample";
            String endpointAddress = "opc.tcp://"+hostname+":6002/UAExample";
            myServer.bind(bindAddress, endpointAddress, SecurityMode.ALL);
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////


        //////////////  CLIENT  //////////////
        // Load Client's Application Instance Certificate from file
        KeyPair myClientApplicationInstanceCertificate = ExampleKeys.getKeyPair("client", 2048);
        // Create Client
        Client myClient = Client.createClientApplication( myClientApplicationInstanceCertificate );     
        //////////////////////////////////////      


        /////////// DISCOVER ENDPOINT ////////
        // Discover server's endpoints, and choose one
        EndpointDescription[] endpoints = myClient.discoverEndpoints( "opc.tcp://"+hostname+":6002/" ); //51210=Sample Server
        // Filter out all but opc.tcp protocol endpoints
        endpoints = EndpointUtil.selectByProtocol(endpoints, "opc.tcp");
        // Filter out all but Signed & Encrypted endpoints
        endpoints = EndpointUtil.selectByMessageSecurityMode(endpoints, MessageSecurityMode.SignAndEncrypt);
        // Filter out all but Basic128 cryption endpoints
        endpoints = EndpointUtil.selectBySecurityPolicy(endpoints, SecurityPolicy.BASIC128RSA15);
        // Sort endpoints by security level. The lowest level at the beginning, the highest at the end of the array
        endpoints = EndpointUtil.sortBySecurityLevel(endpoints); 
        // Choose one endpoint
        EndpointDescription endpoint = endpoints[endpoints.length-1]; 
        //////////////////////////////////////      


        ////////////  TEST-STACK  ////////////
        // Create Channel
        ServiceChannel myChannel = myClient.createServiceChannel( endpoint );
        // Create Test Request      
        TestStackRequest req = new TestStackRequest(null, null, null, new Variant( "Hello World" ));
        System.out.println("REQUEST: "+req);        
        // Invoke service
        TestStackResponse res = myChannel.TestStack(req);       
        // Print result
        System.out.println("RESPONSE: "+res);       
        //////////////////////////////////////      


        /////////////  SHUTDOWN  /////////////
        // Close channel
        myChannel.closeAsync();
        // Unbind endpoint. This also closes the socket 6001 as it has no more endpoints.
        myServer.getApplication().close();
        //////////////////////////////////////      

    }

}
```

TestStackService.java

```
package org.opcfoundation.ua.application;

import org.opcfoundation.ua.common.ServiceFaultException;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.core.TestServiceSetHandler;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.core.TestStackExRequest;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.core.TestStackExResponse;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.core.TestStackRequest;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.core.TestStackResponse;
import org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.endpoint.EndpointServiceRequest;

/**
 * Service handler that implements stack test
 * 
 */
public class TestStackService implements TestServiceSetHandler {

    public void onTestStack(EndpointServiceRequest<TestStackRequest, TestStackResponse> req) throws ServiceFaultException {
        req.sendResponse( new TestStackResponse(null, req.getRequest().getInput() ) );
    }

    public void onTestStackEx(EndpointServiceRequest<TestStackExRequest, TestStackExResponse> req) throws ServiceFaultException {
        TestStackExResponse res = new TestStackExResponse();
        res.setOutput( req.getRequest().getInput() );       
        req.sendResponse( res );
    }

}
```

I can't find any java event/listener import packages or any method calls to these on... methods. How are these methods triggered?

Answer (score 0):

This is the key:

```
    // Add a service to the server - TestStack echo
    myServer.addServiceHandler( new TestStackService() );
```

The server then triggers the TestStackRequest to be handled by TestStackService (which implements the respective interface).

Comment: Hey Jouni Aro Are you developed your code for Android then i need your help please suggest and reply. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You can get help for Android development from Prosys OPC, for example from http://www.prosysopc.com/blog/developing-opc-ua-for-android/ - but this requires the commercial SDK. The OPC UA Stack is usually not enough for basic application development, unless you are ready to implement all "SDK level" features yourself. More about the Stack/SDK levels at http://www.prosysopc.com/opc/

Comment: I worked out using the linkas you provided but the Issue is i suffered from Last two days and got Errors while connect as NO SECURITY PROVIDER AVAILABLE!

Comment: For Android, you must include the Spongy Castle libraries (sc*.jar)  in the Build Path and make sure they are included in the Order & Export section as well.

Comment: Hi Jouni i was already added scprov-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar file in My Projectand also configure with build path.

Comment: There are three sc*.jar files that must be added

Comment: Ok i will checked it Out and give reply soon